# A White-Walled Castle

Tags: riddle

> I am a castle with plain white walls
>   but on my inside are no halls.
>
> My creator laid me down with care -
>   all smooth corners, never square.
>
> Inside my door you must create,
>   You'll find my prize, my gold estate.
>
> And though it cannot walk, it runs -
>   Unless you burn it 'til it's done.

**What am I, and what's my prize?**

Comment: Reminds me of "Marble walls, as white as milk" https://riddlesbrainteasers.com/marble-walls-white-milk/

Comment: The idea behind that one is actually pretty similar - I wish I didn't know this had beaten me to it!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are ...

> An egg

I am a castle with plain white walls but on my inside are no halls.

> The white walls are the eggshell

My creator laid me down with care all smooth corners, never square.

> The shell is always rounded - no sharp corners on an egg.

Inside my door you must create, You'll find my prize, my gold estate.

> You must create a "door" by cracking the shell.  Inside is the golden yolk.

And though it cannot walk, it runs Unless you burn it 'til it's done.

> An egg is runny, unless it is cooked completely (some would say burnt)

Comment: Great! Also, rot13(gur jbeq "ynvq" vf va ersrerapr gb n puvpxra ynlvat na rtt). Everything else, you got!

Comment: [I beg to differ](https://news.rspca.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/Square-eggs-in-a-nest-%C2%A9-Freedom-Food.jpg).

Comment: @TheLethalCoder You're about 4 months late ...

Answer (score 6):

Are you

> a candle?

I am a castle with plain white walls

but on my inside are no halls.

> Could be a plain white candle such as one you'd find in a church; on the inside is a wick instead of any halls.

My creator laid me down with care -

all smooth corners, never square.

> Candles are usually round, and when they're created from molten wax they're very fragile -- you need to handle with care so you don't get burned and don't deform the candle.

Inside my door you must create,

You'll find my prize, my gold estate.

> The door could be the top of the candle, and the prize could be either the wick or the fire that you must create by lighting the candle.

And though it cannot walk, it runs -

Unless you burn it 'til it's done.

> The candle wax will run as it melts from the fire, until you burn it all the way to the bottom.

Comment: Nope, but I like your reasoning!

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> An igloo

I am a castle with plain white walls

but on my inside are no halls.

> There are made out of white snow, and it has only one room.

My creator laid me down with care -

all smooth corners, never square.

> Line snow bricks placed in a circle.

Inside my door you must create,

You'll find my prize, my gold estate.

> You need to live in a shelter if it is very cold and the gold estate may be a fire or warmth.

And though it cannot walk, it runs

Unless you burn it 'til it's done.

> I am not sure.

Comment: Good guess, but not what I am looking for!

Answer (score 5):

Can I just say that the first thing I think of is "White Castle"? ((Tasty!))
Alas, are you:

> A toaster

I am a castle with plain white walls

> It's a box that is traditionally white (nowadays I guess they're *silver*).

but on my inside are no halls.

> Well... it ain't a castle.

My creator laid me down with care -

> You don't put toasters next to your stove, in a microwave, or in a bathtub, for instance.

all smooth corners, never square.

> I don't know about you guys, but our white old toaster is rounded on its edges. This seems to be the case with a lot of toaster designs... I don't know why.

Inside my door you must create,

> Create some *toast*. If it has a door though, it might be one of those *fancy* toasters. You know the ones.

You'll find my prize, my gold estate.

> Toast 'em till they are golden brown... *mmmm*

And though it cannot walk, it runs -

> Would you count them popping out at the timer "running"? They're running from the heat! ha. ha. Or the timer "runs" out of time- ticking down until it pops the toast out.

Unless you burn it 'til it's done.

> You can burn toast easily. Also relates to above, "running" out of time and all-the-while burning that bread.

What am I, and what's my prize?

> Toaster & Toast

Comment: That's a clever answer! Not what I was looking for though - sorry!